# MVC3 Wildcard scriptmaps in IIS6

Tags: iis-6, mvc, web-platform-installer

I'm moving an asp.net MVC3 appliaction from its test box to the live server. I've noticed that although its been working on the test box

Windows Server 2003 Web Edition SP2

there is no wildcard scriptmap in place (at the website or the 'websites' level) : I thought that was needed for IIS6, and I thought IIS in the above server was IIS6...

So, why does the above site work. I think I installed ASP.NET MVC3 with the Web Platform Installer. That mentions something about IIS7 Preferred Configurations. Is it something to do with that, and is that something I can replicate to the live boxes? The live servers currently need the wildcard scriptmap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there perhaps a set of scriptmaps (including a wildcard) at the Application level?

AFAIK:

- If your MVC app was deployed to
  http://server/ , you'd need a
  wildcard at the site level.
- If it's deployed to
  http://server/appdir/ , you just need
  it at the appdir level.

Edit: All becomes clear... http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx - the ASPNET_ISAPI filter can take care of this as of .Net 4.0. (It's also used for handling the cookieless session state URLs in earlier versions - it just got a bit more versatile).

Comment: not that I can find. The app is deployed as a website, there is no scriptmap there, and none at the webserver level (right clicking on websites and exploring properties). If there is a command line way of exploring these settings I'd be happy to run it!

Comment: This article http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs looks like it steps through the possibilities for setting up MVC2, at any rate - an ASP.net handler can be invoked if your site is architected to use that (i.e. uses a particular extension as part of the path). for command lines: cscript adsutil.vbs get /lm/w3svc/1/root/ScriptMaps (or target /w3svc, or /1/root/yourapp/scriptmaps, and so on)

Comment: The issue is exactly that I didn't have to follow the steps from that article on my test server, but I do have to on the live server...and I have no idea why the test box is "special" - presumably something I or others have done to it in the past! The command line shows I have a wildcard scriptmap in another application in another folder running in a different app-apool under a different version of dot net. Other than that, I can't see what makes this tick!

Comment: Dang! - just seen your edit. Thanks! That must be what was going on. I should be able to get that to work on the new server too then! Thanks for your research @TristanK That was driving me mad!